# Unable to get the access token from WSO2 API Manager by using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator(ESB) API/Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

**Requirement**

I have to create an API in WSO2 Integrator to generate the access token by using wso2 APIM accesst token endpoint with client_credentials grant with the below details.

```
  WSO2 token endpint -  http://myapim:8243/token
  grant type  - client_credentials
```

I have created as sequence in wso2 integrator and with an endpoint as shown below but the am unable to generate token for the below code.

```
<sequence name="AccessToken" onError="ExceptionHandler" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg value="client_credentials"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
     
    <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Basic SmhUMfgfgfgfgfkjkjkjkjkLaXNh"/>
    <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    <log level="full"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="post" uri-template="http://myapim:8243/token">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

**Error:-**
Getting the below warnings

```
Connection time out after while in state : REQUEST_DONE Socket Timeout : 180000 correlation_id : null Remote Address : localhost/127.0.0.1:8290
[2020-09-09 19:39:29,814]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} - Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:cf3c34a9-2dd5-4947-b0e9-7d2d19922140 and correlation_id : null But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
[2020-09-09 19:39:29,821]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
```

**Expected Response**

Need to create WSO2 ESB/EI API or proxy to invoke the WSO2 APIM token endpoint to generate access token with client_credentails grant.

Comment: Did you tried with HTTPS:8243 and a call mediator ?